# Rsyslog : wrong properties with reverse tunnel

Tags: reverse, rsyslog, tunnel

better if i show an example:

original message, from host-A

> {"@timestamp":"xxxxxxx","@version":"1","sysloghost":"host-A","severity":"xxxxxxx","facility":"xxxxxxx","programname":"host-A-app","procid":"xxxxxxx","relayhost":"host-A","relayip":"host-A","message": {xxxxxxx}}}}

message after reverse tunnel

> {"@timestamp":"yyyyyyy","@version":"1","sysloghost":"localhost","severity":"notice","facility":"user","programname":"","procid":"-","relayhost":"localhost","relayip":"127.0.0.1","message":{"@timestamp":"xxxxxxx","@version":"1","sysloghost":"host-A","severity":"xxxxxxx","facility":"xxxxxxx","programname":"host-A-app","procid":"xxxxxxx","relayhost":"host-A","relayip":"host-A","message": {xxxxxxx}}}}

as you can see, properties have been replaced (original content is now the value of 'message' property).

I could extract original properties with some RegExp, or text searching, but i think should be a way to keep the original values.

Anyone, help?

Answer (score 0):

I did more googling and found this https://gist.github.com/marshyon/583f75d35e45a6075ed1#file-server-rsyslog-conf-with-reverse-ssh-tunnel

Basically, dedicated ports, one for each host.

I wonder if there are more solutions ...